# Inheriting From a Generic List

Tags: c#, list

I feel like I should know this the answer to this question but I am not 100% if this approach would work how I think it would. If I make Generic T Collection class that has an overrideable list. If I made a bunch of new features for the generic list. Would the classes that override the list with the generic add, insert, and etc. allow other objects that are not the desired object into the list? I think it wouldn't allow it but at the same time since the Add and Insert would allow any object to get passed into the T Collection. So lets say if I override the list to a type of Human, would the add methods let other types like cat be inserted to that list?

```
[Serializable]
    private class List<T> : IList
    {
        private virtual IList<T> wrappedList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a non-generic IList wrapper
        /// around a generic IList&lt;T&gt; interface.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="wrappedList">The IList&lt;T&gt; interface to wrap.</param>
        public List(IList<T> wrappedList)
        {
            this.wrappedList = wrappedList;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert the given parameter to T. Throw an ArgumentException
        /// if it isn't.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">parameter name</param>
        /// <param name="value">parameter value</param>
        private static T ConvertToItemType(string name, object value)
        {
            try {
                return (T)value;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException) {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(Strings.WrongType, value, typeof(T)), name);
            }
        }


        public int Add(object value)
        {  
            // We assume that Add always adds to the end. Is this true?
            wrappedList.Add(ConvertToItemType("value", value));
            return wrappedList.Count - 1;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {  wrappedList.Clear(); }

        public bool Contains(object value)
        {
            if (value is T)
                return wrappedList.Contains((T)value);
            else
                return false;
        }

        public int IndexOf(object value)
        {
            if (value is T)
                return wrappedList.IndexOf((T)value);
            else
                return -1;
        }

        public void Insert(int index, object value)
        { wrappedList.Insert(index, ConvertToItemType("value", value)); }

        public bool IsFixedSize
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return wrappedList.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        public void Remove(object value)
        {  
            if (value is T)
                wrappedList.Remove((T)value); 
        }   

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {  wrappedList.RemoveAt(index);}

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get { return wrappedList[index]; }
            set { wrappedList[index] = ConvertToItemType("value", value); }
        }

        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            if (array == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

            int i = 0;
            int count = wrappedList.Count;

            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", index, Strings.ArgMustNotBeNegative);
            if (index >= array.Length || count > array.Length - index)
                throw new ArgumentException("index", Strings.ArrayTooSmall);

            foreach (T item in wrappedList) {
                if (i >= count)
                    break;

                array.SetValue(item, index);
                ++index;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return wrappedList.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public object SyncRoot
        {
            get { return this; }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {  return ((IEnumerable)wrappedList).GetEnumerator(); }
    }
```

Here is inheritance class

```
private class List<Human> : List<T>
{ 
     private override IList<Human> wrappedList 

}
```

If I add items to List would it allow me to add items that aren't human since its add method gets inherited from List. I wouldn't think it would allow it since I say Human. This is the behavior I would expect but just making sure.

Comment: You're going to have to show your code.

Comment: Code is often clearer to understand than narrative, but it sounds like you are describing a Collection Class which *might* inherit a generic but also might *use* a generic collection for storage yet implement  the methods you mention.  `List<T>` is sometimes a bad idea to inherit from because the consuming code has so much access to things like sorting and clearing

Comment: @Plutonix does that make more sense?

Comment: you do know that is not VB.NET code, right?  It also looks like you are trying to violate the type constraints

Comment: @Plutonix Yes I do that is C#. I don't have the VB code written yet. I was just wanted to make sure before I started to make a generic T Collections class that all my other collections inherit that I can do what I am wanting and not allow the add and inserts to let a different object be added the the list.

Comment: dont u want to write extensions to List?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can put a type constraint on `T` so it will only allow certain types, and rather use `IList<T>` as the interface you implement

Comment: @GeneR Yes that is the point is I want to add new features that will apply to all collections. My issue is now we have every collection have its own Add method that only lets one object type into the list. I was wondering if the add stayed in the List Class and just override the list to a different object type would it still work the same

Comment: @3dd How would you put a constraint on top of the add function?

Comment: ` private class List<T> : IList<T> where T : YOUR_CONSTRAINT`  Thus you can only create a list that will allow your objects and add will only accept types of you want

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this?

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void AddHuman(this IList<Human> list, Human item)
    {
         list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

and using:

```
var list = new List<Human>();
list.AddHuman(new Human());
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics operate on the specific type or interface (and it's base classes/base interfaces). The commonly used "T" is the type placeholder that will exist on this object when you create an instance (to replace the T with an actual type).

Your example inheritance class will actually not compile at all.  The type inference only works when you're creating an instance or specifying it in the class inheritance/interface implementation chain.  You could do something like this:

```
private class MyHumanList : List<Human> { }
```

This will essentially be the same as `List<Human>`.

"Cat" could not be inserted into this list because the generic methods only allow "Human" objects to be inserted into it, but that too depends on the inheritance relationship of Human and Cat you've defined.

If "Cat" can be successfully cast to Human (if you've defined "Human" as the base class of "Cat"), it can be added via the various Add/Insert methods exposed by the base `List<Human>` object.